# Cant change text color to white

Tags: css, typescript, material-ui

I'm new to Typescript and trying to change the text to white but I can't figure out how.

Hope anyone can help me in the right direction.
I seem to be stuck and have tried many different ways and solutions but cant seem to find or figure It out.

This is my code

```
type ExploreCardsProps = {
    avatar: string
   headgear: string
   amount: number
   }
   const ListText = styled(ListItemText)(()=>({
    color: "white",
   
}))


 export function ExploreCards ({avatar, headgear, amount} : ExploreCardsProps)  {
  return (
    
    <List sx={{ width: '100%', maxWidth: 360, bgcolor: 'black'}}>
      <ListItem alignItems="flex-start">
        <ListItemAvatar>
          <Avatar alt="Luis" src= {avatar} />
        </ListItemAvatar>
        <ListItemText 
          primary="Headgear"
          secondary={
            <React.Fragment>
              <Typography
                sx={{ display: 'inline'}}
                component="span"
                variant="body2"
              >
               {headgear}
              </Typography>
              {amount}
            </React.Fragment>
          }
        />
      </ListItem>
      <Divider variant="inset" component="li" />
      
    </List>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace the `ListItemText` component with the `ListText` component in order for your custom styles to be applied.